# Splitting String Into Array Of Words

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am working on a C function to split a string of letters into an array, however it keeps seg faulting and I have no idea why.

I have run it through DDD a few times, it was not of much help.

```
char* stringToArray(const char *desc)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *array[5][10] = {{0}};/*5 words, 10 chars each*/

    while (desc[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (desc[i] != ' ') {
            *array[j][i] = desc[i]; /*seg faults here*/
        }

        else {
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return **array;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: Each `array[J][I]` is a pointer. You haven't made any of all those pointers point to somewhere valid.

Comment: ahh ok, so I want to remove that * and off we go

Comment: You also shouldn't return a pointer to a stack allocated variable (`array`). That won't work.

Comment: Thanks, found that out just before, changed the function to a void and its no longer returning anything.

Comment: Removing the `*` works **only** locally, inside the function. Once the function returns the array ceases to exist and the return value (the pointer to the inexistent array) is unusable. Consider passing to the function the array that receives the words.

Comment: returning char* for an array of strings??

Comment: whats the best / cleanest way to pass 'array' to my other function? I am having trouble coming up with a signature for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make your array static or allocate some memory for it - returning a pointer to a local array won't work.

You also might want to check out strtok.